# expeditionary force problem

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

I had a small problem when playing as the UK. US send me 3 divisions in an Expeditionary force and when I went to the province they arrived at, they were under French control. It happened three other times with smaller exp-forces, didn't think much of it at first.

But when I sent ten divisions in an exp-force to Romania-after the Axis invaded-they didn't come under Romanian control, but French. I have no idea how or why. Anyone able to explain this to me?

I am fully open to the idea I was doing something wrong, but I can't think of anything myself.